# push checked item details to an array and updating the array based on check/uncheck using vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a products json with multiple details like this below.

**products.json**

```
products: [
        {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "Cake-WhiteForest",
            "manufacturer": "Cake Cafe",
            "category": "WhiteForest",
            "color": "White",
            "available": true,
            "address": "16th Lane",
            "quantity": 8,
            "description": "milk chocolate wafer",
            "price": 12,
            "delivery": "small"
        },
        {
            "id": "10",
            "name": "Donuts-Choco bun",
            "manufacturer": "Donut House",
            "category": "Choco bun",
            "color": "chocolate",
            "available": true,
            "address": "13th Avenue",
            "quantity": 14,
            "description": "Donuts with dark chocolate",
            "price": 13,
            "delivery": "minibox"
        }
       ]
```

I am displaying these products name with checkbox like a list with formatted name(like tag) like this:

```
CheckBox1  Cake-WhiteForest
CheckBox2  Donuts-Choco bun
```

**methods:** (checkbox change event)

```
check(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      let files = this.products.find(item => item.id === e.target.value)
      this.getCheckedProducts.push(files)
    }
  }
```

**Component Code for this**

```
<li
                v-for="file in products"
                :key="file.id">
                <span>
                  <input type="checkbox"
                         :id="file.id"
                         :value="file.id"
                         v-model="checkedFiles"
                         @change="check($event)"/>
                  <span class="doc_input">
                    <i class="el-icon-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="product__name">
                    {{file.name}}
                  </span>
                </span>
              </li>
```

Now, problem is if i checked both items of list then its pushing both items correctly into 'getCheckedProducts' array. If i uncheck any of the checkbox but it is not updating. There are still two items. How to update the state of checkbox?

V-model log showing prototype details. How to use v-model for this? Because i am passing array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid creating `getCheckedProducts` manually. You have a variable `checkedFiles` that already contains the ids of the checked products. If you use a computed property `checkedProducts` based on `checkedFiles`, your computed property with products will be automatically updated when you check or uncheck a checkbox, because it will automatically update the v-model, and subsequently update all computed properties that depend on it.

```
computed: {
  checkedProducts() {
    // Map ids to their corresponding products
    return this.checkedFiles.map(
      id => {
        // Assumption: All ids in checkedFiles actually have a product in the products array
        return this.products.find(product => product.id === id);
      }
    );
  }
}
```